# how to run ShowCase more than one time and center text

Tags: android

Hi i need to show the ShowCase provided here: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

i must add:

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(main)
    .setTarget(new TargetView(R.id.spinner, main))
    .setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
    .setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button")
    .hideOnTouchOutside()
    .build();
```

what im doing is adding the .setShowCaseViewListener after the build, and inside the onviewhide, i add another, and than go on (very nested)

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(main)
            .setTarget(new ViewTarget(R.id.statusFilterSpinner, main))
            .setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
            .setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button")
            .hideOnTouchOutside()
            .build().setOnShowcaseEventListener(new OnShowcaseEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShowcaseViewHide(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {

            new ShowcaseView.Builder(main)
                    .setTarget(new ViewTarget(R.id.status, main))
                    .setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
                    .setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button2")
                    .hideOnTouchOutside()
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowcaseViewDidHide(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onShowcaseViewShow(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {

        }
    });
}
```

and how can i align the text? i tried changing the style of it, but nothing worked...

```
   <style name="CustomTitle2" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title">
        <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fa220909</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Bare in mind, this is deprecated.

Comment: humm, is there any other to use on his place?

Comment: No, not that I can find, I am just letting you know what is says on the readme. The main developer is not supporting it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the previous ShowCaseView try something like:

```
@Override
        public void onShowcaseViewHide(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {
            showcaseView.hide();
            new ShowcaseView.Builder(main)...
        }
```

I can't change your textAlign, but I'll tell you when I find the answer.

In order to make several steps, you must hide the previous manually in case it doesn't do itself. Clicking the Ok button will hide it, but if you want to hide the showcaseView while clicking into the circle it won't hide itself. For this case, you only have to change your implementation on 'onShowcaseViewHide' to 'onShowcaseViewDidHide' and this should work.

I hope I would help you.

Comment: thanks the answer, you know how to add more than one and they go in sequence? i can add, but they overlap each other =/